# Problems working with the output of the YouTube_It gem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been messing around with the Youtube_It gem for the past couple of days as I'm trying to integrate it into a Rails 4 app I'm currently working on.

When I run a search query with it, it outputs an array with a ton of results. As long as I'm in the Rails console, there's no problem with manipulating it. A brief example :

```
require 'youtube_it'

client = YouTubeIt::Client.new(:dev_key => "dev_key")  

data = client.videos_by(:query => "penguin")

data.videos.each { |v| puts v.unique_id }
```

This outputs a nice, tidy list of all the unique id's that were returned from the query.

When I try to do something similar within a view (I know it shouldn't really be in the view, it's simply there for testing at this point) it just outputs a huge jumbled list of what appears to be XML. This only seems to happen when I try to iterate using .each.

When I do something like :

```
<% data = client.videos_by(:query => "penguin") %>

<%= data.videos[1].unique_id %>
```

This returns exactly what I was expecting, one unique_id from the index that I chose. Great! But how do I get ALL the unique id's?

That's where I'm stuck and would really appreciate some help! :)

Comment: it doesnt make sense that the same thing would render different things from different places. Are you sure that if you use the same code from the view (you haven't used the same code here), you get a different result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, two reasons (working from the gist you gave me on IRC, located [here](https://gist.github.com/kevlarmusik/6930909)):

1) You are not actually using the same code as in the console. Your console uses `puts unique_id` which will print the value of the unique ID, but you are just using `unique_id` which will get the ID... and then do nothing with it. What you want is probably something like `data.videos.map(&:unique_id)` (or `data.videos.map { |v| v.unique_id }` in long form) which will return you an array of the IDs.

2) You are using `<%=`, which means 'evaluate this ruby line and output the return value onto the page'. The return value of an each statement is the object you called each on - ie. `data.videos`, so that is what is getting printed out.